# How does the toString method display an entire list of objects without iterating a loop?

Tags: java, jvm, javac

Well, I'm starting to study Java now and the following question came up, if I have a list of objects, and I override the toString method, as java can show all the values of the objects in the list, without iterating with some kind of for ?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<AB> p = new ArrayList<>();
         p.add(new AB("tst1", 25));
         p.add(new AB("tst2", 22));
         System.out.println(p);    
    }
}
```

---

```
public class AB {
                
      String name;
      int age;

      public AB(String name, int age) {
          this.name = name;
          this.age = age;
      }

      public String toString() {
           return name + " " + age;
      }
}
```

So my question is I'm not actually stepping through objects as all object values are displayed using toString ?

Comment: The `toString` method for `ArrayList` comes from `AbstractCollection`, which uses an `iterator` to loop over each element and calls it's `toString`

Comment: @MadProgrammer As well ? Could you explain me better or send an article that talked about it? Att.

Comment: You can dig into the source code, follow the `extend` path till you find where `toString` is overridden ;)

Comment: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/8549d8b5697606ef87bb3f72abcf14dd7eb8a151/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#L438

Comment: @MadProgrammer OK, as I said before, I'm quite a layman in Java, in this case the toString method that is being called first is from the ArrayList class that extends AbstractCollection and then calls the toString of the AB class that I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` extends from `AbstractList` which extends from `AbstractCollection` which overrides the `toString` method (defined in `Object`)

This then iterates over the list of elements, calling their `toString` methods which, in the end, generates the `String`

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (! it.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = it.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(',').append(' ');
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, but I want to confirm. In my AB class I'm overwriting the toString or in my AB class I overwrite the toString of the Object class, after I instantiate a list of type AB, the toString is overwritten again now using the one from the AbstractCollection class, is that it?

Comment: No, it's not overridden again.  It's called, internally, the JVM is using a lookup table to determine what should be called, but that's low level detail.  All you care about is when `sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);` is executed, your class's `toString` method is invoked (the snippet will call `toString` - it's compiler magic)

Comment: @YuriBittencourt I think you need to understand how Java generics work. In particular, the behavior known as "erasure". The List<AB> you allocate is a plain ArrayList, and the toString method is the one that ArrayList inherits from AbstractCollection. Here's a little trick you can use to see what's happening. In your toString method, add this line: `new Exception().printStackTrace();`

Comment: @boneill I inserted the line you sent me, it showed the output, so as I understand it, it calls my Class's toString, then it calls valueOF, I think it's to convert that int age to String, then it builds the string with Builder, only after it calls the toString method of the AbstractCollection class, then it calls the valueOf again and finally it calls the stream and it stays like that recursively until it finds all the items, at least that's what I understood, oh and the toString method of the class AbstractCollection is being called and not overwritten, is that it?

Comment: Another thing, as I said, I'm very new to java and most of the courses I see around don't teach these things, I would like to understand a little more about the low level, have a very solid foundation, which books do you recommend, technical blogs, articles, etc, would help me a lot @MadProgrammer